# Insert batch in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5. I have tried to insert the following data in laravel using Insert. But not working anymore.

I have $permission array which contains the following array detials.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [permission_id] => 1
        [role_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [permission_id] => 2
        [role_id] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [permission_id] => 3
        [role_id] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [permission_id] => 4
        [role_id] => 1
    )
)

DB::table('permission_role')->insert($permission)
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'any more'? was it working before? are you getting any error?

Comment: Actually I have got a error message... But now working fine.. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array
(
    array
    (
        [permission_id] => 1,
        [role_id] => 1,
    ),

    array
    (
        [permission_id] => 2,
        [role_id] => 1,
    ),
    array
    (
        [permission_id] => 3,
        [role_id] => 1,
    ),
    array
    (
        [permission_id] => 4,
        [role_id] => 1,
    )
)
```

Comment: how does this solve the problem and how come this array of arrays any different from the one in question?

Comment: @Pinka, thanks. I have changed the array(comma was missing).