# Why Eloquent Doesn't support Batch Insert?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I was playing with laravel Eloquent and found that it doesn't support **Batch Insert** i.e.multiple row at once like

```
Model::insert($array_of_data);
```

What is the reason for this ?

Thank you for any suggestion .

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm)? If not, what do you expect to see as a suitable answer?

Comment: I think you can ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356345/insert-batch-in-laravel-5

Comment: @raina77ow yeah i have seen this answer, but using query builder it doesn't update timestamps right??

Comment: But there was [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26569967/1229023) in that thread dealing with timestamps, no?

Comment: Yes,  And Yes we can do this batch insert in many ways in our own but my question is why it is not in eloquent yet ??

Comment: We're not the ones to ask why. You'll want to go directly to the coders for that. We just work with what they've built.

Comment: and i think knowing these thing is not illegal :) , right ?

Comment: Are you sure using SO for this particular question is better than using Laravel issue tracker - [which actually already has one](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1295)?

Comment: I thought i will get some idea about this issue here so i posted it in SO. But now  i think i should close the question . :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't because of for models you might have extended logic. For example when creating new database entry you might want to to verify previous records to find out for example this record identifier and doing it with single query is not possible, so you can either you use [batch inserts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts) using query builder or simple use loop to create many records but in case of multiple records in 2nd case it might obviously affect performance.